# How many simultaneous calls are available over Twillio Elastic SIP Trunking with a single number?

Tags: twilio, sip

Trialing elastic sip trunking from Twillio with  one number attached. My PBX  wants me to input number of simultaneous calls and I do not find references to  that in Twillio docs

3CX pbx

Comment: https://www.twilio.com/docs/sip-trunking/scale-and-limits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

[Elastic SIP Trunking](https://www.twilio.com/sip-trunking) is built to allow for unlimited concurrent calls. I think your PBX likely wants this information because older suppliers of SIP trunks would sell you connection with that sort of limit and the PBX would need to handle the limits for you.

My colleague Devin dropped a link into comments that shows [the limits of Twilio's Elastic SIP Trunking](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sip-trunking/scale-and-limits). The limit applicable to your question is:

> Unlimited concurrent calls

If your PBX really won't let you move on without a number then I recommend you estimate the maximum number of simultaneous calls that you will need and enter that. Or just any really big number. Twilio will handle it.

Comment: Great ! Thank you.

Comment: Useful to know that as I was in trial, the limit has been 4... from same link.

Answer (score 0):

3CX PBX have licence basic of simultanious calls [4,8,16,31 etc.], so even if Twillio is unlimited You will be limited to 3cx licence

Comment: That is right too, of course, I would put the above number of calls the same as my 3cx license (currently 8)